# Scaling on android devices beyond 480x800

Tags: android, layout, scale

I have a small Android app which works fine on resolutions up to WVGA (480x800), however beyond this the layouts don't scale (for instance for the Galaxy TAB 1024x600) but appear in the top in the middle (with black borders down sides and at bottom). The layouts look fine in Eclipse at these resolutions.

What Am I doing wrong?

Am I missing something in the manifest?  Do I need to supply high resolution resources?

Comment: Can you share your layout xml?

Comment: Have you looked at the article for supporting multiple screens? http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 2):

Try putting this in your manifest.

```
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#xlarge

Answer (score 1):

putting

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />
```

In the correct place in my manifest solved the issue.  For some reason I had placed it under `<application>`.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a tool that allows you to scale/adjust your layouts for tablets and small screen devices and made a blog post about it here: http://onemanmobile.blogspot.com/2012/04/how-to-scale-your-android-layouts-to.html

Basically, defining your layouts in dp units is not enough if you want your app to fit on all devices and tablets, since there's 4 different "density-buckets". The tool will allow your layouts to be converted into fitting these density buckets.

It will also explain in further detail how to make flexible view components.